# Is there an mdl add on for blender v2.79

Tags: add-on

I've tried various searches on the net and attempted to install the add-ons but none work with v2.79 . Has anyone found an .mdl addon that does work ? . Thanks

Comment: have you tried de-compiling the .mdl with crowbar to get a .smd or .dmx file that CAN be imported into blender using the "blender source tools"

Comment: Thanks Samir . I've tried the Cannon Fodder decompiler which worked perfectly as far as I can see . The problem I found is the Source tools not loading